# Deny POST Requests Except to Specified URLs in NGINX

Tags: post, nginx, http-post, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

We would like some advice and code examples on denying all POST requests except to specified URLs on NGINX.  Of course, we need to avoid the "if is evil" if possible.

We would like to block POST requests for the entire vhost except to URLs specified.

We have looked at similar questions on here and nothing answers the query precisely.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: This seems to be an exact answer to your question. https://serverfault.com/questions/637908/how-to-deny-post-to-a-url-in-nginx

Comment: Yes, it partially answers the question regarding limiting POST requests but does not mention anywhere about whitelisted URLs where POST requests are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

use exact determination in the config

```
location = /publish/domain.io.php {
  allow all;
}
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

Combining the two examples.

```
location = /publish/domain.io.php {
  allow all;
}
location ^~ /publish{
  limit_except GET {
    deny  all;
  }
}
```